# How to check or validate username existance in database using onBlur in Angular-Meteor

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am creating a registration form in Angular-Meteor.

For that I need to check if username already exist in database or not using on blur.

How can I achieve that in Angular-Meteor?

I am using Accounts-Password package and meteor.users table is not allowing to query all users emails.

Following code returns empty result:

```
Meteor.users.find({username: username}).fetch
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this on the client side, you won't get any results because the `Meteor.users` collection is normally not populated (using a subscription) on the client-side. And you probably don't want to do this. I'd suggest creating a server side method that checks the existence of a username and which only returns true or false.

By the way, you can see what Meteor actually has available on the client side, by running `Meteor.users.find().fetch()` within your Javascript console.